# Not able to :create even though I'm using protect_from_forgery :except => :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, authentication, devise

I am using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 1.9.3 with Devise.  So I have a **User** model and also an **Order** model.

I would like to be able to use the **:create** function in the Order model **without using authentication** or signing in, but my app keeps asking me to be signed in after I click `Submit`.

I'm using a static form that looks like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/orders" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="order[image]" value=""><BR>
    <input type="text" name="order[name]" id="name" value="lolly"><BR>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I am also trying to use `protect_from_forgery` as mentioned in other resources.

Here is what the top of my application_controller.rb file looks like:

```
# Uses CSRF Protection except on create action
# Except :create action of orders
protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

Any additional suggestions or resources in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Protection from forgery is separate from, and has nothing to do with signing in or authenticating, and should not be skipped. This essentially allows a malicious person to submit form data that bypassed CSRF token verification.

Comment: As for the app asking you to be signed in, check which callbacks are defined on your `create` action, and look for one that's requiring a logged in user. That sounds like the problem.

Comment: @jefflunt can you post the orders controller I think that you are not getting the variables into params